# Data analysis - MD analysis Python

Tags: python, mdanalysis

I am seeing this error, need help on this!

warnings.warn("Failed to guess the mass for the following atom types: {}".format(atom_type))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "traj_residue-z.py", line 48, in 
protein_z=protein.centroid()[2]
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: 2 is a too big index. Your centroid have less dimensions. You should check protein.centroid()[0], and protein.centroid()[1]

Comment: The warnings is likely harmless. I don't know why `protein.centroid()` does not return an array with 3 elements. Without seeing code I cannot really answer the question.

I'd encourage you to ask on the MDAnalysis mailing list https://groups.google.com/group/mdnalysis-discussion or on the MDAnalysis Discord (see https://www.mdanalysis.org/#participating ). Debugging problems is a lot easier when we can discuss directly.

Comment: Thanks for the information and posted as mentioned.

Comment: Malo - I checked and didn't worked

Comment: The are some steps you could take to make your future questions a little more clear and informative. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Providing an overview of what you're trying to do, what you have tried, and what is going wrong will make it easier for people to understand your problem and offer help. You've included the traceback, which is very helpful, but it's also important to include a snippet of the problematic code. And by asking clearer questions you'll be much more likely to get useful help sooner!

Comment: @Paul Sure. I will make a note of it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved through a discussion in the mailing list thread https://groups.google.com/g/mdnalysis-discussion/c/J8oJ0M9Rjb4/m/kSD2jURODQAJ

In brief: The [traj_residue-z.py](https://groups.google.com/g/mdnalysis-discussion/c/J8oJ0M9Rjb4/m/HXOxBYJODQAJ) script contained the line

```py
protein=u.select_atoms('resid 1-%d' % (nprotein_res))
```

It turned out that the selection `'resid 1-%d' % (nprotein_res)` would not select anything because the [input GRO file](https://groups.google.com/g/mdnalysis-discussion/c/J8oJ0M9Rjb4/m/67b3Blp6DQAJ) started with resid 1327

```
 1327LEU      N    1   2.013   3.349   8.848  0.4933 -0.2510  0.2982
 1327LEU     H1    2   1.953   3.277   8.893  0.0174  0.1791  0.3637
 1327LEU     H2    3   1.960   3.377   8.762  0.6275 -0.5669  0.1094
 ...
```

and hence the selection of resids *starting at 1 did not match anything*. This produced *an empty AtomGroup `protein`.*

The subsequent centroid calculation

```py
protein_z=protein.centroid()[2]
```

failed because for an empty AtomGroup, `protein.centroid()` returns an *empty array* and so trying to get the element at index 2 raises `IndexError`.

The [solution (thanks to @IAlibay)](https://groups.google.com/g/mdnalysis-discussion/c/J8oJ0M9Rjb4/m/6P61KgB7DQAJ) was to

- either change the selection string `'resid 1-%d'` to accommodate start and stop resids, or
- to just select the first `nprotein_res` residues `protein = u.residues[:nprotein_res].atoms` by slicing the ResiduesGroup.